# Check if a file is a directory or a regular file in Python 2.7.11

Tags: python, directory

I have written this code for checking if some of the files in a particular directory are further files or directories.

My file structure is like like:

```
C:\Users\Desktop\pythonprograms
|-temp1
|-temp2
|-sample.py

import os

filepath = os.getcwd()
backslash = "\\"
allfiles = os.listdir(filepath)

for indexval in range(filelist):
   print "File  ", indexval, allfiles[indexval], type(allfiles[indexval])   
checkfileisdir = filepath + backslash
dirsavailable = [checkfileisdir + indexval for indexval in allfiles]
for checkfile in dirsavailable:
    print os.path.isdir(checkfileisdir)
```

The above code returns True for the directories as well as the files.

Further, the following code does the trick of solving the problem. I am looking for explanations rather than code snippets.

```
for indexval in range(filelist):
   print "File  ", indexval, allfiles[indexval], type(allfiles[indexval])           
   checkfileisdir = filepath + backslash + allfiles[indexval]
   print os.path.isdir(checkfileisdir),
```

I am not able to explain why. Can someone help me learn?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `filelist` you are iterating over in your code?

Comment: Did you mean to do `isdir(checkfile)`?  Right now you are running `isdir(checkfileisdir)` on the same `checkfileisdir` variable over and over again.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use incorrect function for your task.

Read in [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html)

> os.listdir
>
> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory
>   given by path. The list is in arbitrary order. It does not include the
>   special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the
>   directory.

***entries in the directory*** here is any kind of entry (file, directory, etc)

You need to use this function:

> os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)
>
> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (dirpath, dirnames, filenames).

[Here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) is a good usage example

Comment: Not clear how this is related to the question.  It's perfectly reasonable to iterate over the entries returned by `listdir` and see if they're files or directories.

Comment: Author has at least compiler error in his code **range(filelist)** - filelist is not defined above. Also here iterating throw all entries, so it could be much easy to got all directories in one list and all files in another